# Is it possible to select place holder image for products without changing configuration in admin or directly uploading to magento folder ?

Tags: product-images, placeholder

Is it possible to make magento show my place holder images which is stored in a particular folder without changing the admin configuration or directly uploading file to magento default folder.

What i am expecting was is there a config file which I can say these are the placeholder images and pick these in magento ?